# The proper usage of CSS selector first-child

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like to know is there any proper usage of `:first-child`?

Both CSS options do exactly what I want. But I wonder if option 1 is `:first-child`'s normal usage as I think this is a pseudo class. Does it need to bind with sth else in front of it, just like the option 2 does?

Here is a codepen [link](https://codepen.io/cheukfungtse/pen/BaNgZae) if you wanna try out. Thank you very much for answering my question.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>testing 1</h1>
  <h1>testing 2</h1>
  <h1>testing 3</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
//option-1
.wrapper {
  :first-child{
    color: green;
  }

  :last-child{
    color: red;
  }
}

//option-2
.wrapper {
  h1:first-child{
    color: blue;
  }

  h1:last-child{
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Comment: the second selector will add more restriction. It will select the first-child only if it's a h1. YOu can see the difference if you have different elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif So there is no proper usage of ```:first-child```. It's all depending on how strict you want to select your element? If I wanna have specific criteria. Should it be good  to use ```first-of-type```?

Comment: yes there is no *proper* usage. It all depend on what you want to select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through with this example:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/4ogqptna/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>this is paragraph</p>
  <h1>testing 1</h1>
  <h1>testing 2</h1>
  <h1>testing 3</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    //option-1
.wrapper {
   :first-child{
    color: green;
  }

  :last-child{
    color: red;
  }
}

//option-2
.wrapper {
  h1:first-child{
    color: blue;
  }

  h1:last-child{
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

I have added an extra `p` before `h1`, so for `wrapper` class it doesn't mind which element is as first element so you can see there is `green` color for `p` but there is no color for `h1`(first child of h1).

now, the second `option-2` will work only if the first child of wrapper class is of `h1`, as per my fiddle it doesn't have that element as `first-child` because `p` is sitting on top of it, so there is no change in the color for the first child of `h1`.

hope it helps!

Comment: Let's see if my understanding is correct. 

option 1 : select the first-child under wrapper class, ignoring what kinds of element it is.
option 2: select the first-child which needs to be h1 and also under the wrapper class.

Comment: yep, that's correct. first option irrespective of any child it display that. For the second to work it should be of type `h1`. you got it!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) is the definition with examples of using `:first-child`. And yes it is a pseudo-class. It will select only the first child element among siblings. So therefore it must be the first child of its parent if you want to select it. In option 1 you applied `:first-child` on any (*) first child element which comes directly after the parent element. In option 2 you specified exactly which first element you want it to be applied on.